# zurb-foundation sections -> wierd whitespace introduced when navigating sections

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I feel like a moron. I'm experimenting with zurb foundation sections. I'm on the latest version 4.3.1.

I'm following the docs they have here:  http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/section.html and i'm getting wierd behaviour when navigating results. see screenshots below. **What am I doing wrong?**
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here's my code

```
<form data-abide action="">
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-24 columns">
        <div class="section-container auto" data-section>
            <section class="section">
                <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel1">Panel 1</a></p>
                <div class="content" data-section-content><p>Content of section 1.</p></div>
            </section>
            <section class="section">
                <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel2">Panel 2</a></p>
                <div class="content" data-section-content><p>Content of section 2.</p></div>
            </section>
            <section class="section">
                <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel3">Panel 3</a></p>
                <div class="content" data-section-content><p>Content of section 3.</p></div>
            </section>
            <section class="section">
                <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel4">Panel 4</a></p>
                <div class="content" data-section-content><p>Content of section 4.</p></div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
dysplay:none
```

for non-active content and

```
dysplay:block
```

for active

Comment: thanks @anon. are you saying zurb intends for me to add event bindings  to handle this myself? My impression is that this functionality should be handled by the zurb sections feature.

Comment: I saw that this property is contained in the CSS-file in the example. try to write this property in your file

Answer (score 0):

argh. My bad. I thought I had upgraded foundation, but it turns out something was screwy with my rubygems environment paths.

After **really** upgrading to 4.3.1 the issue isn't there anymore.